# How to create a visual basic dialog box that users can input text

Tags: vb.net, dialog

I have a program that lets users create very basic images with a picture and a greeting. I want the user to be able to select the text.

```
Public Sub setText(ByVal aMessage As String)
    fmessage.Text = aMessage
```

This is the method i want to invoke. How do I create a dialog box that lets users input what they want so that `fmessage` holds that value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want an `InputBox` I think

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx

```
dim myValue as String = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter Value", "Please Enter Value")
```

Comment: It's probably sufficient for this application. Since InputBox is an old VB6 dinosaur with very terrible customization your are nearly always better off with creating your own little inputbox form and showing this form with the `.ShowDialog` method, or a function the returns the set value when you click OK or something along this line.